# How to stop music if Enter key is pressed anytime the program is running?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, audio, winsound

I want my program do something along the lines of:

***while this program is running: 

    if the `Enter` key is pressed, stop the current music file playing.***

---

Here is my code:

```
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html

from msvcrt import getch
import winsound

while True:
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 13:
        winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_NOWAIT)

winsound.PlaySound("SystemAsterisk", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
winsound.PlaySound("SystemExclamation", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
winsound.PlaySound("SystemHand", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
winsound.PlaySound("SystemQuestion", winsound.SND_ALIAS)

winsound.MessageBeep()

winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/Admin/My Documents/tone.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

winsound.PlaySound("SystemAsterisk", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

---

In the documentation (see link in the first line of my code), I am unsure weather `winsound.SND_NOWAIT` can be used like this: `winsound.SND_NOWAIT()`, or like how I tried to use it in my code under the `if` statement, or if both statements produce the same effect.

It is my understanding that the program will never get to play the sound files until after I press the `Enter` button, as the `getch()` part *requires* before continuing.

However, even if that part of the code does not care *when* I press anything, wouldn't the program get stuck in the `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

The linked documentation for `winsound.SND_NOWAIT` states that:

> **Note:** This flag is not supported on modern Windows platforms.

Besides that I don't think you understand how `getch()` works. Here's a link to its documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak

And here's another for a related one named `kbhit()` (which `msvcrt` also contains and I use below):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx

The following will stop the loop (and the program, since that's the only thing in it) when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. Note that it doesn't interrupt any single sound already playing because `winsound` doesn't provide a way to do that, but it will stop any further ones from being played.

```
from msvcrt import getch, kbhit
import winsound

class StopPlaying(Exception): pass # custom exception

def check_keyboard():
    while kbhit():
        ch = getch()
        if ch in '\x00\xe0':  # arrow or function key prefix?
            ch = getch()  # second call returns the actual key code
        if ord(ch) == 13:  # <Enter> key?
            raise StopPlaying

def play_sound(name, flags=winsound.SND_ALIAS):
    winsound.PlaySound(name, flags)
    check_keyboard()

try:
    while True:
        play_sound("SystemAsterisk")
        play_sound("SystemExclamation")
        play_sound("SystemExit")
        play_sound("SystemHand")
        play_sound("SystemQuestion")

        winsound.MessageBeep()

        play_sound('C:/Users/Admin/My Documents/tone.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        play_sound("SystemAsterisk")

except StopPlaying:
    print('Enter key pressed')
```