# How to create typing indicator with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have made a real live chatroom in Python with `tkinter`.

I want to know how to create a typing indicator without using firebase. What I mean by this is that say, one of of the user's name is `bob`, and if bob is typing a message I want it to say to the other users that `bob is typing...` and I want it, if possible, to appear over the type message box.

## Edit:

I added this in:

```
def var_changed(self):
   self.label.config(text=msg+"is typing")

my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()
my_msg.trace = ("w", var_changed)
entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.pack()
```

but it all it is doing is copying what i'm writing instead of saying user typing a message

## Server.py

```
import socket, threading

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen()
clients = {}
addresses = {}
print(host)
print("Server is ready...")
serverRunning = True

def handle_client(conn):
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
        welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % data
        conn.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
        msg = "%s has joined the chat" % data
        broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
        clients[conn] = data
        while True:
            found = False
            response = 'Number of People Online\n'
            msg1 = conn.recv(1024)

            if msg1 != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
                broadcast(msg1, data+": ")
            else:
                conn.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
                conn.close()
                del clients[conn]
                broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % data, "utf8"))
                break
    except:
        print("%s has left the chat." % data)

def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)

while True:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    conn.send("Enter username: ".encode("utf8"))
    print("%s:%s has connected." % addr)
    addresses[conn] = addr
    threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (conn,)).start()
```

## Client.py

```
import socket,threading,tkinter

host = input("Enter server name: ")
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
address = (host,port)

def echo_data(sock):
   while True:
      try:
         msg = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
         msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
      except OSError:
         break

def send(event=None):
   msg = my_msg.get()
   my_msg.set("")
   s.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
   if msg == "{quit}":
      s.close()
      top.quit()

def on_closing(event=None):
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chat Room")

messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()
my_msg.set("Type your messages here.")
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
msg_list.pack()
messages_frame.pack()

entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.pack()

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

address = (host,port)
s.connect(address)

threading.Thread(target=echo_data, args = (s,)).start()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't support multi-threading—meaning that only one thread can update the GUI. This means, for example, that `echo_data()` can't directly update the tkinter `Listbox`. The common workaround is usually implemented by using a `Queue` to pass data between the threads and periodically checking it in the QUI thread to see if any new data has arrived. You can schedule the polling using `tkinter`'s universal [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method. There are a number of answers here showing how to do that here if you search for them.

Comment: @martineau I have researched `Queue` and `after()` and kind of understand but what would the code be for detecting if someone is typing something in?

Comment: I think detecting if someone is typing without blocking is going to be OS-specific and do not think Python provides anything generic to do that specifically. On Windows, for example, you could use `msvcrt.kbhit()`. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113705/how-to-stop-music-if-enter-key-is-pressed-anytime-the-program-is-running) to a question with an answer showing its use. I don't know about other OSs, However—once again—it's very likely there are some questions here on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: create typing indicator for `tkinter.Entry` widget

1. Define Application class inherited from `tk.Tk`, for demonstration only.

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   class App(tk.Tk):

       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
   ```
2. Init a Flag `.is_typing`, to know typing was detected

   ```
           self.is_typing = False
   ```
3. Create a `Entry` as common

   ```
           self.my_msg = tk.StringVar()
           entry_field = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.my_msg)
           entry_field.grid(row=0, column=0)
   ```
4. Bind a `'<KeyRelease>'` event to the `Entry` instance which for every key release event calls the function `self.typing(...`

   ```
           entry_field.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.typing)
   ```
5. Create a `Label` and `Button` for demonstration purpose only

   ```
           self.label = tk.Label(self)
           self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)

           btn = tk.Button(self, text='Send', command=self.send_msg)
           btn.grid(row=2, column=0)
   ```
6. Reset the flag `.is_typing` and clear the `Label` text on sending the message, for demonstration only.

   ```
       def send_msg(self):
           self.is_typing = False
           self.label.config(text="")
   ```
7. The function `def typing(...` which get called on every key release event.
   Return without further action if the flag `.is_typing` are set.
   If the flag is **not** set, this is the first call:

   - Set the flag
   - Do the action, her only set the `Label` text to `"is typing"`.

     ```
     def typing(self, *args):
         if self.is_typing:
             return

         self.is_typing = True
         self.label.config(text="is typing")
     ```
8. Run the demonstration app

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       App().mainloop()
   ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: do I have to add this in and not do anything to the other code?

Comment: @system123456: This is a demonstration example, have you tried it and does it met your requirements? If yes, you need point 2, 4 and parts from 6 and 7.